# Stopping autoslide of a slider programatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a slider jquery plugin. The slider starts automatically in autoplay, but when the mouse hovers the slider it stops. There's a function for this, of course.

My problem comes when i have a movie inside one of the slides. if the movie is playing, i want to stop the autoplay completely even if the mouse isnt hovering the slider.

How can I call the "stop_autoslide" function inside the plugin, from outside it's code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind) a custom event inside your slider-plugin.

```
$(sliderObject).bind("stop_slide", stop_autoslide);
```

And then [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) it from anywhere with:

```
$(".mySlider").trigger("stop_slide");
```

Depending on how your plugin works you might need [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live) instead of bind.